# Intel Core i9 9900T

Tags: processor, desktop, intel

According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191044/intel-core-i9-9900t-processor-16m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html) the i9-9900T  was launched in Q2'19 but I can't find it in any retailers or online.

I have tried some other T designated CPUs and no luck with those either.

I am interested in the T designated CPUs for their low power specs, which imply lower heat dissipation hence lower noise in their cooling.

Is the i9-9900T available for end-users at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can buy the I9-9900T as an end-user. See e.g. here: https://clevo-computer.com/de/komponenten-zubehoer/prozessoren-cpus/intel/intel-9th-gen-coffee-lake-r/intel-core-i9/1392/intel-core-i9-9900t-8x-2.10ghz-tray-cm8068403874122

Adding a bit of speculation: it was probably never intended by Intel to reach the end-user market as a stand-alone product. Hence why only the tray version is available, and no "boxed" version.

Further speculating on the intended use-case: if availability is a problem in your part of the world, you can just emulate an I9-9900T. Buy a regular I9-9900, und underclock/undervolt it. You will get pretty close in terms of power consumption.
And if lower noise is your original motivation to get this CPU in particular, investing in a decent aftermarket cooler will absolutely help with that.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the tray versions of CPUs to be an "end-user" product because the original sale of full trays are sold to OEMs in bulk orders. Also, the tray CPUs might come with a different warranty than the boxed CPUs, depending on the reseller. But that's just semantics, you can still buy a single CPU taken from a tray, but through distributors and online sellers rather than retailers (which only get consumer boxed CPUs).

Comment: That was exactly the point I was trying to make in the second paragraph

Comment: @MechEng Thanks for your input. Where can I learn about underclocking/undervolting and what is Intel position on those practices?

Comment: The procedures are basically the same as with overclocking, a topic which will show up many more guides when you enter it into the search engine of your choice. Only instead of aiming for the highest clock speed, you optimize towards lowest possible voltage at a lower clock speed. Not sure if Intel has a public position on that, but it's not like they would monitor what you do with your CPU ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some CPU models are only sold to OEMs in trays for building PCs, such as the i9-9900T in this case.

There are many resellers selling CPUs from a tray, which MechEng has pointed out in their answer. So they are *technically* available to end-users but they are essentially 2nd-hand CPUs. Without sealed retail packaging, you might not be able to tell whether it has been installed in a system before.

Keep in mind that Intel's tray CPUs [are not covered by any warranty.](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000024255/processors.html) The only support you will have for the CPU will be from the reseller, if any.